# Что отражает фокуса управления?

Tags: uml

Что отражает фокуса управления (прямоугольник на линии жизни) в диаграмме последовательности?

И в чем принципиальное различие этой схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и этой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нашел лекцию на интуите на эту тему, но для ответа там слишком много, лучше почитайте там http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/32/32/lecture/1014?page=1, если совсем кратко: первая схема синхронная, вторая асинхонная, вроде так